# Use Single Fragment in Multiple tabs of ViewPager

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, fragment, android-recyclerview

I am using ViewPager to slide left and right, I have also added the tabs, The number of tabs is depends on the server data, So, I cannot make the number of tabs as Fixed. To do this I used only Single Fragment and a RecyclerView to display JSON Data in the recyclerView.  When First app launches, the data which should be shown in 2nd tab is getting displayed in 1st Tab itself. After I swipe to 3rd Tab and come Back again to 1st Tab, then the data is displaying correctly.

It is as same as GooglePlayStore. I think there is only one fragment, because the UI is same in all the tabs.

Here is the code to Add Fragment and displaying data to recyclerView.

PagerAdapter.java

```
    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    List<List<ProductInfo>> data;



    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumofTabs, List<List<ProductInfo>> data) {
        super(fm);
        mNumOfTabs = NumofTabs;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       /* ProductFragment pf = ProductFragment.newInstance(data.get(position),position);
        return pf;*/

        return ProductFragment.newInstance(data.get(position),0);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Fragment.java

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {
   private static final String ARG_PRODUCTS = "PRODS";
   private static List<ProductInfo> allProducts;
   int position = 0;
   RecyclerView prodList;


public static ProductFragment newInstance(List<ProductInfo> products,int position) {        
    ProductFragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList(ARG_PRODUCTS, (ArrayList<ProductInfo>) products);
    args.putInt("KEY_POSITION",position);
    args.putInt("KEY_ID",id);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //if(isVisibleToUser){
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            allProducts = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PRODUCTS);
            this.position = getArguments().getInt("KEY_POSITION");
        }
   // }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
    prodList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_list);
    return view;
}



 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    prodList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    prodList.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), allProducts));
    Log.e("ProductFragment " ,"" + allProducts.get(position).getName());
}
```

EDITED:
Activity.java

```
onCreate(){
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    allProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Category cat : catList) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(cat.getName()));
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        //tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        allProducts.add(cat.getProductsList());
    }
 viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(), allProducts);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Log.e("ViewPager "," getCurrentItem() "+viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

 }
```

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your Activity code and PagerAdapter code.

Comment: Add your activity code.

Comment: Edited.... Plz check

Comment: @Drv.... Updated question.  please check it dude

Comment: @Dharvikshah Edited dude

Comment: @DemoMail I have the same problem..please reply if you got the solution?

Comment: @vicky  Did you solve it? I too have this problem

Comment: @Visakh check for accepted answer.

Comment: @MohdAsifAhmed its not working for me, I am fetching data on the Fragment itself by an HTTPcall. This method does not make any change :(

Comment: why are you calling httpcall in fragment, call in activity, and based on that use fragment

Comment: @MohdAsifAhmed I have added question with reference to your question. Please check my code there.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816494/using-only-one-fragment-with-recyclerview-for-multiple-tablayout-not-updating?noredirect=1#comment92554559_52816494

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PagerAdapter edit as below, it might help:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   /* ProductFragment pf = ProductFragment.newInstance(data.get(position),position);
    return pf;*/

    return ProductFragment.newInstance(data.get(position),position);
}
```

And in your Fragment make changes as below:

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_PRODUCTS = "PRODS";
private static List<ProductInfo> allProducts;
int position = 0;
RecyclerView prodList;
ProductAdapter productAdapter=null;


public static ProductFragment newInstance(List<ProductInfo> products,int position) {        
ProductFragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelableArrayList(ARG_PRODUCTS, (ArrayList<ProductInfo>) products);
args.putInt("KEY_POSITION",position);
args.putInt("KEY_ID",id);
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
  if(isVisibleToUser){
      productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}



  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //if(isVisibleToUser){
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            allProducts = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PRODUCTS);
            this.position = getArguments().getInt("KEY_POSITION");
        }
   // }
   }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
prodList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_list);
prodList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
productAdapter= new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), allProducts)
prodList.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        return view;
   }
}
```

Comment: prodList.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), allProducts));     //NullPointerException occurs at this line in setUserVisibleHint

Comment: productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   //Now here NullPointerException

Comment: Please debug and try to find why it is giving nullpointer and also post your logs so that I can also help.

Comment: @Drv i am using the same code, but the problem is my recycler view of the last tablayout scroll and recycler view for the previous tablayout doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

change this line in : **PagerAdapter.java**

```
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          ProductFragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putParcelableArrayList(ARG_PRODUCTS, (ArrayList<ProductInfo>) products);
          args.putInt("KEY_POSITION",position);
          args.putInt("KEY_ID",id);
          fragment.setArguments(args);
          return fragment;
        }
```

and remove static method from fragment as :

```
public static ProductFragment newInstance()
```

bcoz this static method set data of the latest page from viewPager. and FYI viewPager load next page in memory in advance. and static method makes it show now rather then show in future.

Comment: I will add images, how it is looking

Comment: ya sure. please add.

Comment: Please check the images, 1st is when app launches and displayes eggs items in Starrer, The 2nd image is when i swipe till end tab and again come back by swiping, the data is correct

Comment: when i click on tab instead of swipe, then also data is not correct

Comment: okay i will try to help u as soon as i get free. keep in touch : dharvikca@gmail.com. best luck if u get ur answer early.

Answer (score 0):

I had a smaller issue, I was using a single fragment with multiple TabLayout. I kept getting the wrong position in my fragment which was the last position in the TabLayout.

The problem is saving fragment position in a static variable or in Bundle will save the last created fragment and the ViewPager will create fragment ahead of the current position so that is why we're losing the current position.

So what I've done to solve this issue is creating a local variable holding the tab position of the created fragment.

The code in Kotlin

```
class TabFragment : Fragment() {
private var tabPosition = 0

companion object {
    fun newInstance(tabPosition: Int): TabFragment {
        val tabFragment = TabFragment()
        tabFragment.tabPosition = tabPosition
        return tabFragment
     }
  }
}
```

The code in Java

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {
private int tabPosition = 0;
static TabFragment newInstance(int tabPosition){
    TabFragment tabFragment = new TabFragment();
    tabFragment.tabPosition = tabPosition;
    return tabFragment;
  }
}
```